# Site ads based on conferences made by users of said site

Tags: discussion, support, advertising, community-promotion-ads

I come over from [PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com), and a few of the people in chat are [talking about organizing a conference of sorts](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32384074#32384074). This conference would have direct links to the PPCG site (what with coming from the site and all).

Say that a conference was to be held by a SE user relating to an SE site, with no revenue and hosted by a wing of an NPO. Would this conference be an appropriate as part of the specific site's advertising?

Comment: You do realize PPCG has [community ads](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9463/community-promotion-ads-2016), right? What's the difference?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I'm not sure if it's appropriate to place ads _related_ to the site yet not exactly _run_ by the site.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Ahh, i see that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only is this perfectly OK, but it's exactly what community ads are for, and is explicitly allowed on the [community ads meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9463/31716). To quote [Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/146126/grace-note):

> This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:
>
> - the site's twitter account
> - code puzzle blogs and websites
> - interesting challenge sites
> - cool events or conferences
> - anything else your community would genuinely be interested in
>
> The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

In fact, if you look through the 6 currently active community ads, right now *half* of them are about things officially related to PPCG (the twitter account, the sandbox and active bounties). The other 3 are just things that are tangentially related to PPCG, for example [online interpreters](http://tryitonline.net/) and esoteric IDE's.

If an esolang/code-golf conference were to be organized, PPCG community ads would be the *perfect* place to advertise it. (Assuming that it is well received and hits the threshold of 6 votes)

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

A site-specific "community promotion ad" is created with the primary intention of promoting a community and serving content which the users of that community would be interested in. If an ad about a conference receives enough votes to be displayed, then I see no reason to exclude it from the scope.

I have seen all sorts of things on these ads. Like ads for related communities, the Twitter page of the community, or even software relevant to programming for the Code Golf site.

Comment: I take your point (seeing ads relating to TIO is not uncommon).